# What is TWRP doing when it says "updating partition details"?

Tags: twrp

Whenever it decrypts data or applies a zip, it displays the message and then takes a rather long time.

What is it doing during that time?

In `top` I can see that the `recovery` process is fully utilising a core (and more), so it's not like it's sitting around waiting for some timeout either.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: it takes less than a second, something is wrong. so your question should be how to determinate why it takes that long (or how to fix)

Comment: It depends on the situation (it's really fast if I'm just wiping cache) but after decrypting or installing something, it takes over a dozen seconds. If that's not normal, I'd indeed like to know what causes this and how to fix it.

Comment: try disable free space check in settings

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It's updating the partition sizes so that it doesn't get messed up while you're backing up the partition.

*(Source: [partitionmanager.cpp in TWRP source code](https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/blob/9d3ea68bc9e6687e94d2024d772736d80b33c4ef/partitionmanager.cpp#L1554))*

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "get messed up"? Why should anything get messed up when I'm not actually changing any partition sizes?

Comment: You're not changing the partition sizes themselves, but you might be changing the size of the *content* inside of the partitions. You can also see that by the source I mentioned.

Comment: not only. also /etc/fstab is rewritten and all mounts set to default (determinate file system type, decrypt, mount /data, bind mount /data/media/0 to /sdcard, umount /system, etc ...) depending on what action was performed

Comment: As far as what the "Updating partition details..." does *itself*, it only updates the partition sizes for backups.

Comment: Can I disable that? I don't use TWRP's backup feature.

Comment: Nope, sorry. If you go down from the source I mentioned, you'll also see that it updates the free storage size. It's not related to the message *directly*, but it's also a part of that function.